# Symantc Endpoint protection keeps detecting clean file as risk

Tags: virus, antivirus, antimalware, scan

I downloaded some files from website using FTP and these websites have been developed using .net and any .dll file is flagged as Risk by our Antivirus.

[image]

our IT Made some changes to antivirus on my system but it still keeps flagging several .dll files as Risk and this goesnt in loop for ever.

I scanned some of these fils on virustotal.com and they came out clean.

how can i get this fixed without deleting these files.  Unexclude/Undo Action Taken doesnt make any difference.

Here is the link for scan version for details 
https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/b3adf8b825cc10fdd8c1c13c66273022445a80fe894a7a1e18f4fba882b0d204/analysis/1494840803/

How can i get around this or stop Symantec from scanning this file or atleast ignore this file. This is frustrating as it keeps showing popup every 5-6 seconds and goes on for about 15-20 minutes and then stops for about 10 minutes and then starts again. this goes in look

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described on Symantec support website, you can exclude a file or a folder from being scanned by:

> On the Exceptions Policy page, click Exceptions.
>
> Under Exceptions, click Add > Windows Exceptions > File.
>
> In the Prefix variable drop-down box, select a common folder.
>
> Select [NONE] to enter the absolute path and file name.
>
> When you select a prefix, the exception can be used on different
>   Windows operating systems.
>
> In the File text box, type the name of the file.
>
> If you select a prefix variable, the path should be relative to the
>   prefix. If you select [NONE], type the full path name.
>
> Note:
>
> Paths must be denoted by using a backward slash.
>
> Under Specify the types of scans that will exclude this file, select
>   the type of scan (Security Risk, SONAR, or Application control).
>
> You must select at least one type.
>
> For security risk scans, under Specify the type of security risk scan,
>   select Auto-Protect, Scheduled and on-demand, or All Scans.
>
> See the help for information about why you might want to limit the
>   exception to a specific type of security risk scan.
>
> Click OK.

You can check the whole process here : hxxps://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.HOWTO80920.html

Comment: I had shared the share link with IT asked them to mark particular folder as safe. which they did and since then popups have stopped.  https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.HOWTO80920.html#v39818564